# Angular: Problems dynamically creating a component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I tried following various tutorials about how to dynamically create a component but I just can't get it quite right, this is the module which handles the creation of `FilterComponent` on button click (`onAddDataRangeFilter()`):

```
import { Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-collection',
  templateUrl: './filter-collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-collection.component.css']
})
export class FilterCollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  filter: ComponentRef<FilterComponent>;

  @ViewChild("gauges", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  onAddDataRangeFilter() {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<FilterComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FilterComponent);
    const filter = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    this.filter = filter;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

But I get the errors on line 12:

`error TS2564: Property 'filter' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

and line 14:

`error TS2564: Property 'container' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Anyone here who has an idea how to solve these two errors?

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Initialize your variables, it's as simple as that. Or declare them with a !. Like `filter!: ...`

Comment: @R.Richards I understood that but I am not able to come up with an idea how to initialize abstract classes (such as `ViewContainerRef` or `ComponentRef`). Thank you

Comment: `container!: ViewContainerRef` doesn't work?

Comment: Perfect! It does :)